# URL alias or replace with symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have the application which generates urls like this

ex)

```
http://myserver.com/shows/12

http://myserver.com/shows/14
```

My routing.yml is

```
acme_top_writeReviewSchool:
    pattern:  /show/{userId}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Default:showUser}
```

12 or 14 is id used in database.

```
id| name | position
12| james| pitcher 
14| nick | short
15| ian  | catcher
```

Now,what I would like to make alias for this urls

```
http://myserver.com/james

http://myserver.com/nick

or

http://myserver.com/u=james

http://myserver.com/u=nick

or

http://myserver.com/show/james

http://myserver.com/show/nick
```

I have googled with keywords like 'alias' 'url exchange' or something, howevere can't find good example or bundle.

Could you help me?

Comment: You already inserted a dynamic value in the URL which is `{userId}`. What's preventing you from using `{username}` instead? You would just need to retrieve users by using `findAllByName($name);` repository method. BTW, I recommend against using `http://myserver.com/{username}`, you should prepend your URL with some keyword so the app don't mix up the URL's.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have multiple routes pointing to the same bundle:controller:action.

For example if you want to use http://myserver.com/james

```
acme_top_writeReviewSchool_by_name:
pattern:  /{name}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeTopBundle:Default:showUser}
```

The only thing you have to be aware of is that in the controller action you need to either pass the Request object to get either the param "name" or "userId", Alternatively you could name the param the same and manage it by hand (so to speak).

Could you post the controller action here also?